# equality of the spectrum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

$Q$ is non singular and A is hermitian.
$$V_{+}(A)= Span\{  x: Ax=\lambda x, \lambda > 0 \},$$  $$Q V_{+}(Q^H A Q )= Q Span\{  x: Q^H A Q x=\mu x, \mu > 0 \}.$$
Is it true that $ V_{+}(A)= Q V_{+}(Q^H A Q ) $?

And, if it is true,  how can it  be proved?

Comment: Does $Q$ have any special properties?

Comment: it is only non singular

Answer (score 0):

In case you may be interested: If $Q^{-1}=Q^H$, it can be proved to be true.

First, if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $Q^HAQ(Q^{-1}x)=Q^HAx=\lambda Q^H x=\lambda (Q^{-1}x)$. Hence for any $x\in V_+(A)$, we have $Q^{-1}x\in V_+(Q^HAQ)$.

Second, if $Q^HAQy=\mu y$, then $A(Qy)=\mu (Qy)$. Hence for any $y\in V_+(Q^HAQ)$, we have $Qy\in V_+(A)$.